# Changing the last digit of a float

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of geojson data with may points being the exact same.

30.9694313

How would I isolate the last number and random increment it or decrement it landing on either 30.9694314 or 30.9694312?

I guess I could add or subtract 0.0000001, but how to handle this in the event of a dynamic float length?

Comment: So add or subtract .00000001 from it. What is your problem? What did you try?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Question has been edited - its about dynamic float length. Apologies. Eeesh.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic float length"? Do you actually want to flip a bit, not change the decimal representation?

Comment: convert it to the string, split at decimal, and count the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to get a String representation of your float, and then parse the last digit as an integer. Then, you could increment/decrement it, add it back to the substring of your String to replace the old last digit, and parse it as a float. Not sure if this would be the most efficient way to do it, but it's the first thing to pop into my head.

Edit: some methods to help you (links to MDN)

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

[Number.parseFloat(String)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat)

Comment: If you do it this way, you can just get the last digit of the String by using str.charAt(str.length), but I'm sure you already know that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help guys. This is what I came up with. I imagine there might be a cleaner way but this seems to work for me. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

```
noiselocation('-30.12345');

function noiselocation(coord){

    //num to string and strip special chars
    var coordstr = coord.toString();
    console.log('string: ' + coordstr);

    //get length
    var coordstrlength = coordstr.length-1;
    console.log('length: ' + coordstrlength);

    //get last char
    var coordlastchar = coordstr.charAt(coordstrlength);
    console.log('last char: ' + coordlastchar);

    //turn back to number
    coordlastnum = parseInt(coordlastchar);
    console.log('last num: ' + coordlastnum);

    //randomly increment up or down
    var randswitch  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    if(randswitch == "1"){
        coordlastnum++;
    }else{
        coordlastnum--;
    }
    console.log('last num after rand: ' + coordlastnum);

    //replace last char on string
    var newcoordstr = coordstr.slice(0, -1) + coordlastnum;
    console.log('new string: ' + newcoordstr);

    //turn string back to num
    newcoordnum = parseFloat(newcoordstr);
    console.log('new num: ' + newcoordstr);

}
```